# StringFormat Binding to add Suffix to a Bind in WPF, C# Example

Tags: c#, wpf

I've seen examples of binding values and prefixing or suffixing the bound value with stringformat. How is this accomplished in C# code, examples have been in xaml.

```
objBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("Value"); standard Bind
```

Answer (score 1):

How about setting the `StringFormat` property to `Binding` object have you tried that ?

```
objBinding.StringFormat = "prefix {0} suffix";
```